# How to create RAID array using Disks app in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: ubuntu, raid

Ubuntu 12.10 has an app called Disks that used to be called "Disk Utility" and "palimpsest".

This tool used to be able to create RAID arrays, but on a clean install of Ubuntu 12.10, the app no longer has this ability. None of the menus mention anything about RAID.

Was this ability removed? If not, how do I get it back?